# Unable to display XML as ouput in HTML page from razor

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This is a sample XML string that I want to display as ouput on my webpage as such using ASP.NET MVC Razor engine -

```
response_string = 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <response>
        <results>
             <result>
                 <id>1</id>
                 <name>scott</name>
             </result>
             <result>
                 <id>2</id>
                 <name>bill</name>
             </result>
        </results>
    </response>
```

I am returning this string from my controller to _Result.cshtml.

```
XDocument.Parse(response_string).ToString();
```

This is my _Result.cshtml which renders the XML -

```
@model Object
<div>
    <pre>
        @Html.Raw(Model)
    </pre>
</div>
```

The output is getting shown as below (only values) instead of the complete XML text -

```
1
scott

2 
bill
```

Can someone tell why is this so and how can I fix this?

Let me also mention that JSON is getting formatted and displayed properly, but XML seems to be having the problem.

Comment: when you look at the source on the page are you seeing the xml tags?

Comment: This XML is being displayed through an ajax request which populates a div on the page. So, the XML is not visible in the page source. But I can see xml tags from inspect element.

Comment: maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413183/how-to-display-xml-elements-from-within-a-razor-view